# Python threads exit with ctrl-c in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, keyboardinterrupt

I am having the Python Multi-threaded program as below. If I press ctrl+c within 5 seconds (approx), It is going inside the **KeyboardInterrupt exception**.

**Running the code longer than 15 seconds failed to respond to ctrl+c.** If I press ctrl+c after 15 seconds, It is not working. It is **not throwing KeyboardInterrupt exception**. What could be the reason ? I tested this on Linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, threading, time

class Worker(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    # A flag to notify the thread that it should finish up and exit
    self.kill_received = False

  def run(self):
      while not self.kill_received:
          self.do_something()

  def do_something(self):
      [i*i for i in range(10000)]
      time.sleep(1)

def main(args):

    threads = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = Worker()
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    while len(threads) > 0:
        try:
            # Join all threads using a timeout so it doesn't block
            # Filter out threads which have been joined or are None
            threads = [t.join(1) for t in threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Ctrl-c received! Sending kill to threads..."
            for t in threads:
                t.kill_received = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first execution of

```
threads = [t.join(1) for t in threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
```

your variable `threads` contains

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

after the second execution, the same variable `threads` contains:

```
[]
```

At this point, `len(threads) > 0` is False and you get out of the while loop. Your script is still running since you have 10 threads still active, but since you're not anymore in your try / except block (to catch KeyboardInterrupt), you can't stop using Ctrl + C

Add some prints to your script to see what I described:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, threading, time

class Worker(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    # A flag to notify the thread that it should finish up and exit
    self.kill_received = False

  def run(self):
      while not self.kill_received:
          self.do_something()

  def do_something(self):
      [i*i for i in range(10000)]
      time.sleep(1)

def main(args):

    threads = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = Worker()
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        print('thread {} started'.format(i))

    while len(threads) > 0:
        print('Before joining')
        try:
            # Join all threads using a timeout so it doesn't block
            # Filter out threads which have been joined or are None
            threads = [t.join(1) for t in threads if t is not None and t.isAlive()]
            print('After join() on threads: threads={}'.format(threads))

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Ctrl-c received! Sending kill to threads...")
            for t in threads:
                t.kill_received = True
    print('main() execution is now finished...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

And the result:

```
$ python thread_test.py
thread 0 started
thread 1 started
thread 2 started
thread 3 started
thread 4 started
thread 5 started
thread 6 started
thread 7 started
thread 8 started
thread 9 started
Before joining
After join() on threads: threads=[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
Before joining
After join() on threads: threads=[]
main() execution is now finished...
```

Actually, Ctrl + C doesn't stop to work after 15 seconds, but after 10 or 11 seconds. This is the time needed to create and start the 10 threads (less than a second) and to execute join(1) on each thread (about 10 seconds).

Hint from [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

> As join() always returns None, you must call isAlive() after join() to decide whether a timeout happened – if the thread is still alive, the join() call timed out.

Answer (score 0):

to follow up on the poster above, isAlive() got renamed to is_alive()
tried on Python 3.9.6

full code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, threading, time

class Worker(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    # A flag to notify the thread that it should finish up and exit
    self.kill_received = False

  def run(self):
      while not self.kill_received:
          self.do_something()

  def do_something(self):
      [i*i for i in range(10000)]
      time.sleep(1)

def main(args):

    threads = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = Worker()
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        print('thread {} started'.format(i))

    while len(threads) > 0:
        print('Before joining')
        try:
            # Join all threads using a timeout so it doesn't block
            # Filter out threads which have been joined or are None
            threads = [t.join(1) for t in threads if t is not None and t.is_alive()]
            print('After join() on threads: threads={}'.format(threads))

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Ctrl-c received! Sending kill to threads...")
            for t in threads:
                t.kill_received = True
    print('main() execution is now finished...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).